# Site.createPortalUser() takes approx 20-25 seconds for first user registration of the day? Why?

Tags: apex, community, lightning-community, self-registration

We have a Lightning Community and enabled Self Registration.

The issue is weird. It takes approx 20-25 seconds for the very first User registration of the day and all user registrations onwards take only 2.5-3 seconds. We are facing this problem on normal sandbox as well as on partial sandbox also.

Code snippet is as below:

```
public void registerUser(String newUserJson) {
    // This is the input, received from an Lightning Component
    Contact userContact = (Contact)JSON.deserialize(newUserJson, Contact.class);

    // This Account has Owner which has role - No issue here
    Account userAccount = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Individual' LIMIT 1];   

    Profile userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'ABC Community User' LIMIT 1];

    // Setup User data
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.UserName = generateUniqeUserName(userContact.Email);
    newUser.Email = userContact.Email;
    newUser.FirstName = userContact.FirstName;
    newUser.LastName = userContact.LastName;
    newUser.ProfileId = userProfile.Id;

    // If using site to host the community the user should not hit s1 after logging in from mobile.
    String networkId = Network.getNetworkId();
    if (networkId != null && siteAsContainerEnabled(Network.getLoginUrl(networkId))) {
        newUser.UserPreferencesHideS1BrowserUI = true;
    }

    // Compute dynamic nickname for user
    String nickname = ((userContact.FirstName != null && userContact.FirstName.length() > 0) ? userContact.FirstName.substring(0, 1) : '' ) + userContact.LastName.substring(0, 1);
    nickname += String.valueOf(Crypto.getRandomInteger()).substring(1, 7);
    newUser.CommunityNickname = nickname;

    // First Create Contact 
    userContact.AccountId = userAccount.Id;
    INSERT userContact;

    // Create User
    newUser.ContactId = userContact.Id;
    String userId = Site.createPortalUser(newUser, userAccount.Id, password, true);
}

public static boolean siteAsContainerEnabled(String communityUrl) {
    Auth.AuthConfiguration authConfig = new Auth.AuthConfiguration(communityUrl, '');
    return authConfig.isCommunityUsingSiteAsContainer();
}

public static String generateUniqeUserName(String email) {        
    return email + ((isSandbox() == true) ? '.abc.sandbox' : '.abc');
}

public static Boolean isSandbox() {
    return [SELECT Id, Name, OrganizationType, NamespacePrefix, InstanceName, IsSandbox FROM Organization].IsSandbox;
}
```

Please advise what might be taking so long time for simple User registration.

Note: We dont have any other failure in code or complete process, its all about long execution time for only first user registration of the day.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you calculating this *delay*, if you have debug logs then that will suggest which code execution takes time, do you have that information?